# Get object presign url in minio inside openshift

Tags: openshift, minio

I have a Bitnami minio container running in an OpenShift cluster.
When I'm runnig the container locally I'm setting the minio endpoint to localhost:9000 and using dotnet7 SDK I'm able to get object's presigned urls and view them in a browser.
In my OpenShift cluster I named the minio service "minio" and set the endpoint to "minio:9000", but the same dotnet code returns a presignurl that the browsr returns "This site can't be reached".
Looking at this [github issue](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/8007) looks like it is a known issue, anyone found a solution?